# whenPivotLoaded is not working . Always return blank

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, many-to-many

This is my ReportResource file

```
public function toArray($request)
    {   
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->cname,
            'start' => $this->whenPivotLoaded('company_package', function () {
                return $this->pivot->start_date;
            }),
        ];
    }
```

Company Model

```
class Company extends Model
{
    //
    public function packages(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Package')->withPivot('start_date');
    }
}
```

Package Model

```
class Package extends Model
{
    public function companies(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company')->withPivot('start_date');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
return new ReportResource(Company::with('packages')->get());
```

What I am doing wrong .Please help

Comment: What is the error message? Btw, you have twice written semi-colons in models.

Comment: @Tpojka no error message .if  whenPivotLoad() function return false the field will be removed from the response. In here the 'start' field get ignored because whenPivotLoaded return false all the time